# ImageMagik: картинки в ряд разных размеров по высоте

Tags: php, imagemagick

Получилось так, но изображения встают по ширине.

Как сделать так, чтобы они были по высоте, а ширина была автоматическая?

```
$sources = array('1.jpg','2.jpg','3.jpg','4.jpg','5.jpg');

$stack = new Imagick();
foreach( $sources as $source ) {
    $stack->addImage(new Imagick($source));
}

$montage = $stack->montageImage(new ImagickDraw(), '5x1',"50", 0, '0');
$montage->writeImage('out.png');
```

Comment: @Invision [Как получается](https://monosnap.com/file/bcUy8ZO07MprwhspnugWvlR5M9gMbb.png) / [Как хочется сделать](https://monosnap.com/file/Vb2FCxqKznm3QPGUaDxfzmP38RfBPw.png)

Comment: ... не в ту степь меня понесло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да поможет Вам `scaleImage`:

```
    $im = new Imagick('example.jpg');
    $im->scaleImage(0, 300);
    header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
    echo $im->getImageBlob();
```